# Is the local connectedness heritable over the connected subspaces?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, connectedness, locally-connected

**Definition**

A topological space $X$ is locally connected if each point $x\in X$ has a base of connected neighborhoods.

So let be $X$ a locally connected space and let be $Y$ a connected subspace. So if $\mathcal B(x)$ is a local connected base for any $x\in Y$ then the collection $\mathcal B'(x):=\big\{B_x\cap Y:B_x\in\mathcal B(x)\big\}$ is a local base with respect subspace topology on $Y$ and thus the statement follows proving that this base is locally connected but unfortunately I did not able to do this so that I think that the statement is false becouse after all the intersection between two connected set could be not connected however I did not find any counterexample showing that the local connectedness is not hereditable over the connected subspaces. So couldsome one help me, please?

Comment: A convex set intersected with a subspace (which is also convex) is still convex. So it’s trivial.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma My was a lapus: I wanted write **connected** rather than convex. Forgive a lot my confusion: I am really embarrassed for this.

Comment: The plane (locally connected) has plenty of connected but not locally connected subspace. Only open subspaces inherit local connectedness.

Comment: The classic counterexample is the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve): a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^2$ that is connected but neither locally connected nor path connected.

Comment: @RobArthan Oh yeah! I forgot it! Thanks to remember it.

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro it cannot be fixed. A subspace of a locally connected space need not be locally connected.

Comment: Okay, thanks too much for your assistance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, *every* topological space is a subspace of a locally connected space.  To see this, let $X$ be a topological space and let $Y$ be $X$ together with one new point $*$, topologized such that a subset of $Y$ is open iff it is either empty or has the form $U\cup\{*\}$ where $U$ is an open subset of $X$.  Then any two nonempty open subsets of $Y$ intersect, so $Y$ is rather trivially locally connected, and the subspace topology on $X$ is the topology we started with.

Comment: Oh, really wonderful!!! Now it is all clear. Thanks too much for your assistance!